# Error "FeatureNotEnabled" on POST /teamwork/workforceIntegrations

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I've developed a simple Workforce Integration into Shifts App. The registration fails with  an error that the feature is not enabled. Do I need to enable the integration capability on my tenant? I looked through the deployment guide for Kronos integration, but was not able to find anything.

Request:

```
{
  "displayName": "CustomAutoDecline",
  "apiVersion": 1,
  "encryption": {
    "protocol": "sharedSecret",
    "secret": "<64 chars>"
  },
  "isActive": true,
  "url": "https://<myurl>",
  "supports": "Shift, SwapRequest"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"Forbidden\",\"message\":\"Sorry, this feature is not enabled for your team\",\"details\":[],\"innererror\":{\"code\":\"FeatureNotEnabled\"}}}",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "ea894386-6268-47f6-9a38-751a11e996e0",
            "date": "2020-04-07T19:30:13"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the API is actually in preview that why you need your tenant being whitelisted to be able to use the API.